# Boost signature (verify download)

Tags: security, boost, digital-signature, verification

I cannot find a signature (or even checksums) for boost C++ libraries. Only a download link at sourceforge. How can this be trustworthy code?

I know signatures are not perfect, but they do increase the chance that changes (hacks) will get noticed.

Is there boost signatures/checksums somewhere I could verify against?

Comment: If somebody could modify the Sourceforge download, they could change the checksums.

Comment: This is very valid concern. It appears someone need to step up and implement that into their delivery build process :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the MD5 signatures for the V1.45 release:

```
3aa6b9e13268965680c0adf41734f718 *boost_1_45_0.7z 
d405c606354789d0426bc07bea617e58 *boost_1_45_0.tar.bz2 
739792c98fafb95e7a6b5da23a30062c *boost_1_45_0.tar.gz 
4379c7b92bf1ec74cd26908f60920cd1 *boost_1_45_0.zip
```

(as just posted on the [ML](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/64572/focus=64580), but you might have seen it already).

Comment: Please post where you got those from. It would be helpful to find hashes on `boost.org` to verify the downloads on sourceforge